# Drop in Netpune Gremlin Session Query

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Can the "drop()" query work in a Session client in Gremlin queries in Java for AWS Neptune. I have tried a few times but the "drop()" only works if I use iterate() and does not have any effect is the session client is used and query is submitted.

If it does work, it will be helpful to have some examples. It is not very clear from the documentation.

Comment: I did some experiments and was unable to reproduce the issue - see answer below. Can you please share some sample code or the exact way you configured the session and the Gremlin steps that you used?

Comment: Also - which version of the Java client are you using? Neptune currently only supports text queries for sessions until the upgrade to TinkerPop 3.5.x happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some experiments using the Gremlin Console in "session mode". Note that the transaction will only commit once the session is closed.

```
$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/krl6w.yaml session abc-123
==>Configured xxxx-[abc-123]

gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [xxx]-[abc-123] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').count()
==>3503

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').drop()

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').count()
==>0

// This ends the session and commits the transaction
gremlin> :remote close
```

Now to verify it worked

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/krl6w.yaml
==>Configured xxxx

gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [xxxxx:8182] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').count()
==>0
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, the assurance that it works was very helpful. Given that I am new to Neptune/Gremlin. 

Root-cause: It eventually worked for me with sessions, since I was using the string based gremlin I happened to created some of the conditional expressions with %s instead of '%s' which actually caused the issue.

Thanks